# Diablo II Resurrected - Battle.net connection problem

Tags: ps4, battle.net, diablo-ii-resurrected

Today I downloaded the beta of Diablo II Resurrected on the PS4 platform. On PSStore it was available for free to download.
Finally, the game was downloaded in my console, but if I try to run it, I get a warning about Battle.net connection problems. It's surprising, because I have connected the PSN account with Battle.net.

Is it any bug with the beta version of the game or it has to be purchase and this is the reason of connection's fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because D2: Ressurected is not released yet.

It releases on the 23rd of September. The servers will not be available before then.

But why is it on the store and can be booted? There is a Beta coming this weekend, starting on the 20th.

> Following the Early Access weekend, on August 20 at 10:00 a.m. PDT, the Open Beta weekend will be open to everyone on a supported platform.

https://news.blizzard.com/en-us/diablo2/23688836/play-diablo-ii-resurrected-during-the-early-access-and-open-beta

Comment: Ahh, so it is unable to play, because beta will begin on 20 August, but the client was published to download some days before that, right? It makes sense for me, so I am glad that you helped me with solving this mystery :)

Comment: That is very probable. Since its not the official release I guess PSN didn't bother to do a block to prevent booting since, well, you won't get far if the servers don't respond.

Comment: This was the right solution - beta was not launched then :)